# FadeTo & FadeIn doesnt work as they should. multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, opacity, fadein

I wish to create a nice fade effect when pressed a button.

Almost working but theres 1 problem.

When clicked the class="number2 number3" also gets faded.

Is it possible to call --> if class contains value number3 than fadeIN.

I've got the following markup:

```
<div class="mouseclicks"><a href="#">test</a></div>
<div class="number1">tesx1</div>
<div class="number2">tesx2</div>
<div class="number2 number3">tesx3</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
$(".mouseclicks a").click(function(){
$('.number1').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
$('.number2').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
$('.number3').fadeIn("fast",1);

});});
```

**------------EDIT-------------------**

This does fade out the particular number, but doenst get back faded in when pressen button 2.

```
$(function(){
$(".mouseclicks a").click(function(){
$('.number1').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
$('.number2').not('.number3').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
$('.number3').fadeIn("fast",1);
});});

$(function(){
$(".mouseclicks2 a").click(function(){
$('.number1').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
$('.number3').not('.number2').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
$('.number2').fadeIn("fast",1);
});});
```

Comment: change your classNames, my head hurts. You can thank me in a year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mouseclicks a").click(function() {
        $('.number1').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
        $('.number2').not('.number3').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
        $('.number3').fadeIn("fast",1);
    });
});
```

This excludes the div with `class="number2 number3"` from the `.fadeTo()` but the `.fadeIn()` still applies to it

**EDIT**

For the 2-button version, do it like this for button 2:

```
$(".mouseclicks2 a").click(function() {
    $('.number1').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
    $('.number3').fadeTo("fast",0.1);
    $('.number2').not('.number3').fadeIn("fast",1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Only when I have 2 buttons (1 for number1 & 1 for number2) then they dont fade back in at all...

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure what you mean, does `.number3` not fade in when you have two buttons? Can you post the changed code?

Comment: I added to the answer, if you select `$('.number3').not('.number2')` you don't get anything because the only element with class number3 also has class number2

Comment: Got it! Not using FadeIn but fadeTo worked.Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Give them a common parent and you can make it more future proof.

```
<div class="mouseclicks"><a href="#">test</a></div>
<div class="number-wrapper">
    <div class="number1">tesx1</div>
    <div class="number2">tesx2</div>
    <div class="number2 number3">tesx3</div>
</div>
```

-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mouseclicks a").click(function(){
        $('.number3').fadeTo("fast",1).siblings().fadeTo("fast",0.1);
    });
});
```